# how to create a js file to instantiate my smart contract function

Tags: blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts, truffle, ganache

There is an alternative way to the truffle console to instantiate a function of a smart contract, such as a js file that contains the instance of the function and which is then compiled directly on the console?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should check [Truffle Migrations](https://trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/getting-started/running-migrations/). Those are JS files that contain a scenario of deployment - what to deploy and with what parameters. For example, you can both deploy to your local instance of Ganache or Mainnet.

Comment: Thank you very much, it was helpful to me. But is there also a way to reduce the cost of contract deployment?
The code is a simple storage of a bytes32, also because I saw that compared to a string it cost less in terms of gas.
Thank you in advance, very kind